# TFS to Git migration with git-tfs: how to completely disconnect Git from TFS after migration?

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

I successfully cloned a TFS repository, but `git log` still shows HEAD pointing to both master and tfs/default as follows:

```
(HEAD -> master, tfs/default)
```

I already tried the filter-branch command, as well as remove the `[tfs]`, `[git-tfs]` sections from `config`file and run the following commands:

```
git reflog expire --all
git gc --aggressive --prune
git tfs cleanup
git tfs cleanup-workspace
```

But it's still there. The only thing that works is deleting the `.git` folder then running `git init` but of course this loses all history. I also checked `git config --list --show-all` but there is no remote TFS repository in there.

**Question**
Is it possible to completely disconnect TFS from the git repo without losing history after using git-tfs and if yes, how?

---

**EDIT**
The accepted answer works and is instructive but see [this answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/351085/570990) for what I understand is a 'safer' way to do this.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "TFS" repository. Are you talking about TFVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to completely disconnect TFS from the git repo without losing history after using git-tfs

Your git repo is not "connected" to the TFS server. It just contains some data the allow git-tfs to be able to interact with the TFVC source control.

What you see `tfs/default` is a pseudo git remote branch to keep track of the last changeset retrieved.

> and if yes, how?

As it is stored as a git remote, the easier is to delete the file:

`.git/refs/remotes/tfs/default`

Note: if you can't find this file, this is because there is a possibility that the ref is packed in the file `.git/packed-refs`. If there, delete the line corresponding to `refs/remotes/tfs/default`

Comment: It's in packed refs, but there are 5 lines in there: `refs/heads/master, refs/notes/commits, refs/original/refs/heads/master, refs/original/refs/remotes/tfs/default, refs/remotes/tfs/default`. Could you please specify in the answer which one(s) I should remove without breaking something?

Comment: @evilmandarine The answer to your question is already in my previous answer. You should remove `refs/remotes/tfs/default`. The others `refs/original/*` were created when you did a 'filter-branch' or something similar and could in all probability deleted also. But it is easy to test for you. Backup the file and remove the parts to try. See the effect and if it suits you, that's OK otherwise undo the changes. That's how we learn all...

Comment: @evilmandarine see my previous comment (I forgot to mention you so you probably didn't get the notification)

Comment: Your answer works, thank you. I just like to understand what I am doing instead of just trying and seeing if it works. Looking for what are packed refs I found [this answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/351085/570990) and ended up doing `git show-ref default`, then `git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/remotes/tfs/default` and `git update-ref -d refs/remotes/tfs/default`.